# how to use frontend code (html , css) alongside jax-rs in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, frontend, jax-rs, backend

I want to write the backend code of a web application which is going to interact with users (registering users, logging them into their panel, and ...).

my question is that how can I interact with the frontend code? for example, when the user has put all the information needed in order to log in or register, how can I receive this information from the HTML code? how can I set some kind of listener for the time that the user has filled out the form and pressed the, for example, submit button?

I'm using eclipse and resteasy.

Please if anyone has any idea on this, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is found. it is done by adding specific attributes to HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a frontend framework. Eclipse is not a programming language it is just and IDE so that does not matter within the context of your question. You have to ask yourself what language do you want to use for your backend and which framework fits for your frontend. If you are using java a good start is to use springboot as a framework, [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) is a good starting guide. But if you have no experience with frontend so far I would suggest that your first build a basic website just with plain HTML, javaScript and CSS to understand the basics before adding a framework on top.

Comment: There happenend a big misunderstanding for you. I didn't say that eclipse is a programing language. if I'm here asking how to interact with frontend code, it means that I have some background knowledge and experience and can write the backend code but this is where I got stuck with the framework I'm using.sorry to say it but your answer is greatly useless.i said i'm using eclipse for the ones that want to share some code or program structure to know in which ide i'm writing my application.finally if you have no help to offer for my situation do not try to change the way I want to write my app.